# Where did I go wrong with this NAA flag?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I'm curious behind the reason of the declination of my flag, I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809893/how-to-reset-the-primary-key-of-a-table/34089946#34089946) answer as 'not an answer' as it isn't an answer from what I could tell based on the flag description:

> This was posted as an answer, **but it does not attempt to answer the question**. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

(emphasis mine)

I felt that, that answer falls in to that emphasised part of the flag description.

Yet, my flag was declined.

[image]

Surely, an altogether wrong answer should not be kept as it goes against the ethos of the site of gathering a solid knowledgebase of Q&As.

How can an answer be an answer if it isn't answering the question in the requested programming language?

Where did I go wrong in my though process?

---

**Edit #1**

Technical inacuracies are one thing however, what the answerer did was completely different, they did the equivlent of an off-topic question but in an answer form by posting an answer in a completely different technology that was originally specified hence it *should* be classed as NAA. Either that or we need another flag which can handle this sort of instances.

Comment: It's an answer. Might be a short, altogether wrong answer; but it is clearly an answer. The correct course of action is to downvote, not to flag.

Comment: @yivi my point is as I just updated: How can an answer be an answer if it ins't answering the question in the requested programming language? Meaning, that answer isn't directed at the specific question that it is answering on (based on the fact that it is a completely different language). I understand technical inaccuracies but I think that this is taking it too far.

Comment: No, it's not taking it too far. It is still a wrong answer. A wrong answer is an answer. Just downvote it. Comment if you will.

Comment: No need for voting rings. If you find content that's wrong or that's not useful, downvote it. If we do that often enough, content moderation works. But for all our talk and the additional exposure for that answer, it only has two downvotes.

Comment: *"posting an answer in a completely different technology that was originally specified hence it should be classed as NAA"* - you would think so, but then people reviewing flags need to have domain knowledge; in this example case knowing that a particular command does not work in MySQL. Downvotes are simply far more effective to indicate that the answer is wrong. Instantly visible too.

Comment: @HansPassant No, there was not some time in the past where "not an answer" meant, "this answer is wrong".  It has *always* been there to indicate that the post is not even an *attempt* to answer the question, and that it's a request for further information, someone asking a new question, someone saying they have the same problem, etc.  This is not something that has changed.  It was that way from the start.  People have *wanted* the flag to mean "this post is wrong" from the very start, and many people cast that flag for that reason.  It was never correct to do that though.

Comment: @Servy Hans isn't saying that he think the answer is wrong, just that the post doesn't belong in the answer section of that question.

Comment: @Braiam And he's saying that it doesn't belong in the answer section of that question because it's wrong, rather than because it's not actually an attempt to answer the question.  The post is an attempt to answer the question, therefore NAA is not an appropriate flag.  If you don't think it's a *useful* answer to the question, then downvote it.

Comment: @Servy where the heck you see Hans saying that the answer is wrong? He says 1) NAA has been watered-down to become useless; 2)  flagging was intended to alert SO users of issues that need attention; 3) that flagging intention was corrupted; 4) blame's apples and volume; 5) side effect of above is the creation of cabals of users. In no moment Hans says that he believe the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Braiam You're right, that's just the OP.  Of course, Hans also didn't say, "the post doesn't belong in the answer section of that question" as you quoted, so we both misquoted Hans.  But Han's points are all still wrong.  As I said, the meaning of the flag hasn't changed, it has always been for things that aren't answers at all, NAA was originally only handled by moderators, so saying it was originally to alert other users is just wrong, if anything, it's been corrupted by people (like the OP) trying to use NAA to delete *answers to the question*, not the other way around.