# Declined flag for Not an Answer

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Today I got two declined flags on one answer. I can stomach it, but I think that I'm right, so if that's not the case, I'll be able learn and understand inner-working of the site little better.

Answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56785263/5226328

I flagged this answer as question is asking about `static` keyword in recursion, not for implementation. For me it's [example of NAA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553#265553). After I flagged this answer, I edited title to better describe content of question.

I'm okay with my first flag being declined (I believe it were correct flag, but my flag were declined before edit came thorugh, so for declining user it was out of context).

As described on [declined flags help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags) I flagged answer again with custom flag and description:

> My NAA flag was rejected. This question is about 'static' keyword, not implementation. Question states that code is working (and is completely different) so this answer doesn't answer question. I added suitable edit to question to have better title and flagged question as duplicate (but this answer still does not answer question from question body). So it's NAA, and my flag was incorrectly declined.

It was declined again with note (same note as first time):

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I still believe that my flags were correct. Am I right? Were flags declined correctly? If I'm mistaken, then why this answer is not NAA?

Comment: Why didn't you vote that answer, knowing as you know it's not a useful answer?

Comment: @yivi Because it doesn't even answer the question. It is reason for flagging and removal for me. I use usually downvotes for stuff I don't agree (or don't like becouse of e.g. lack of research), but in scope of the site. I probably should downvote (and upvote) more.

Comment: Posts like this can be dealt by the community. But voting is important so the community can eventually act on them, and we send the appropriate signals for future visitors.

Comment: And https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/6296561

Comment: @Zoe - I don't think that this answer is VLQ -  **it would be ok if it would be answer the question**. And on the famous Shog9 image's for me it's "orange" situation, not rotten or green apple.

Comment: @franiis the VLQ and NAA flags are practically identical. They both result in the post being thrown into the VLQ review queue, but VLQ is validated by a non-review edit, while NAA sticks around 'til answer deletion or 'til review is finished.

Comment: @Zoe I didn't know that. But still it doesn't answer my main question. As your linked question (about "try it" answers") doesn't advice deletion, and NAA in this context (IMO) do so. I'm still learning and trying to understand, but whole "meta discussions as documentation" are sometimes confusing.

Answer (score 12):

NAA does not mean "this answer is wrong" it means exactly what it says i.e. it's not an answer at all. Examples of that would be

- Another question
- Complete nonsense such as the cat stepped on the keyboard (although you can flag that as rude/abusive)
- something in a foreign language
- something so grammatically poorly written as to be unintelligible

Moderators cannot be expected to be subject matter experts in every technology so they have no way to validate a flag that claims an answer is simply incorrect. In such a case your options are:

- add a comment explaining why the answer is incorrect
- downvote
- vote to delete if you have such a privilege

You can choose any or all of the above as you wish.

Comment: '*NAA does not mean "this answer is wrong" it means exactly what it says i.e. it's not an answer at all.*' - Though, you cannot deny that NAA with its current description implies that it can be used in the scenario that the OP was in: '*This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.*'. I suggested this a while back due to all the confusion but never got anything from it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377440/can-we-have-the-naa-flag-description-changed

Comment: It does attempt to answer the question, it's just wrong.

Comment: But that's the point of contention here, should it really be classed as attempting to answer if it is not addressing the original question?

Comment: There's no contention, it's pretty settled round here that it should be classed as an attempt.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Answering to another question is attempt? When are hte limits of that? Someone asking hot to declare array in java and answering with great list sorting alorithm in Rust... It's answer, but not to original question. It has to be answer to question, under which it was posted - otherwise we'll heading to chaos...

Comment: @franiis How can we be heading into something that we've been doing since we started?

Comment: @RobertLongson Ok, wrong choice of words. But for me it's perfeclty reasonable to require that all answers answer that sigle given question. If question is unclear or too broad, it isn't good idea to post answer to anything, but to get question to answerable state. So if question is good(or ok) it makes sense to require answer to that precise question. Answer can be good or bad, but it has to be to given question.

Comment: @franiis and how are the small team of moderators supposed to know the difference between java and Rust? Or any other technologies. Of course they are bound to know something, just not everything.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to anger anyone. That's why I added to my flag explanation with reasoning of my flag. I stated what is the real question and why answer wasn't answering that. I don't need to admins know to everything, but they should use data provided by community. And if I was mistaken, then I want to understand why.

Comment: @franiis You're not angering anyone, we're just explaining how it works round here. The only data they have is that one person thinks there's something wrong. That's not the whole community speaking. How can the moderator(s) establish whether that person is correct or not?

Comment: First - flag was raised, so there already is some evidence that there is something wrong. I'm not the most known user, but I have over 400 flags (with over 96% helpful-declined ratio) - maybe this flag also has some merit. I specified reason why this question is none NAA (and this reason is not technology specific). And if one user is not enough for establishing is flag is correct, then each flag is raised by one user (or at least many of the flags).